# Hide controls according to rows from database

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 100 sequential buttons and checkboxes showed in a Windows Forms application, and a database where some numbers are saved.

My aim is to hide the buttons and checkboxes according to the number saved in the database.
For example, in my database I have 4 numbers: 2, 4, 9, and 10. So I want to hide button2, checkbox2, button4, checkbox4, button9, checkbox9, button10, checkbox10.

Here's what I tried:

```
SqlCeCommand cmnd = con.CreateCommand();
cmnd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM register_db WHERE semester = @s AND department = @d AND course = @c";
cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", semester);
cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", department);
cmnd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", course);

SqlCeDataReader rd = cmnd.ExecuteReader();

while (rd.Read())
{
    string number = rd[0];
    button[number].hide();
    checkbox[number].hide();
    // these are the main things that I didn't know how to do                   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All Windows Forms controls have [a `.Hide()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx).  The code is case-sensitive, so you're not calling it correctly.  It needs to be capitalized:

```
button[number].Hide();
checkbox[number].Hide();
```

Alternatively, you can set [their `.Visible` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx):

```
button[number].Visible = false;
checkbox[number].Visible = false;
```

Or are you having trouble with the array of controls?  Names like `button1`, `button2`, etc. aren't particularly meaningful in most cases.  But if your controls are indeed meant to be part of an ordered collection of controls, you can probably just create a collection on your form to represent them:

```
protected IList<Button> Buttons
{
    get
    {
        return new List<Button>
        {
            button1, button2, button3; // etc.
        };
    }
}
```

Accessing the numeric values in the names themselves would otherwise be a job for reflection, which in many cases isn't really the direction you want to go.  It's better to build a structure which meets your needs than to circumvent a structure which doesn't.

With this you can access the controls as an array:

```
Buttons[number].Hide();
Checkboxes[number].Hide();
```

You can take it a step further and combine the two, since they pair together.  Something like this:

```
private class ControlGroup
{
    public Button Button { get; set; }
    public CheckBox CheckBox { get; set; }

    public void Hide()
    {
        this.Button.Hide();
        this.CheckBox.Hide();
    }
}
```

(You can add further error checking within that class to guard against nulls, etc.  Probably give the class a more meaningful name, too.)

Then your collection becomes:

```
protected IList<ControlGroup> ControlGroups
{
    get
    {
        return new List<ControlGroup>
        {
            new ControlGroup { Button = button1, CheckBox = checkbox1 },
            new ControlGroup { Button = button2, CheckBox = checkbox2 },
            new ControlGroup { Button = button3, CheckBox = checkbox3 }
            // etc.
        };
    }
}
```

This keeps things logically grouped together where appropriate into a smarter data structure, which makes the calling code easier:

```
ControlGroups[number].Hide();
```

Comment: Yeah i know but how can i loop button to hide them @David

Comment: @Bayazid: It probably makes even more sense to group the controls into a more meaningful structure, I've updated the answer again to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controls are *named* like that, you can access them through the form’s `Controls` collection:

```
string number = rd[0];
this.Controls["button" + number].Hide();
this.Controls["checkbox" + number].Hide();
```

But you should really put them in a separate list, and probably group them into panels in a `StackedPanel`, or a `CheckedListBox`.